# How do I get JSON data to show up in HTML divs?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this javascript/ajax/json/HTML assignment in uni and its a pizza website where you can build your own pizza. The crust, topping and extra info is in a json file which we have to get to show up on the startpage so you can choose your own kind of pizza. So I'm trying to get data from a JSON file to show up in 3 different divs on my index.html.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Högskolan I Borås Pizza</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="header_top">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header_top_list">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/top_bullet1.png" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/top_bullet2.png" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header_bottom">
                    <div class="header_img">
                        <img src="images/header_img.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/list_img.png" alt="" />Hem</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="pizza.html"><img src="images/list_img.png" alt="" />Pizza</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/list_img.png" alt="" />Kontakt</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="main_top">
                    <h2>Välkommen till vår pizzafabrik på Högskolan</h2>
                    <div class="main_top_strip">
                        <img src="images/main_top_strip.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content_top">
                    <div class="content_top_img">
                        <img src="images/content_top.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content_top_data">
                        <h3>Dagens specialare</h3>
                        <p>Här nedan kan du bygga din egen pizza! Välj botten, topping och extra (dricka, sallad osv).</p>


                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="boxes">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="box_top">
                            <h2>Välj botten</h2>
                            <div class="box_top_img">
                                <img src="images/box_top_strip.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box1_data">


                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box2">
                        <div class="box_top">
                            <h2>Välj topping</h2>
                            <div class="box_top_img">
                                <img src="images/box_top_strip.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box2_data">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box3">
                        <div class="box_top">
                            <h2>Välj tillebehör</h2>
                            <div class="box_top_img">
                                <img src="images/box_top_strip.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box3_data">


                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "botten": ["Krispig", "tunn"]
    },

    {
        "topping": ["kött", "kyckling", "tomat"]

    },
    {
        "extra": ["Fanta", "Coca cola", "Sprite"]

    }
]
```

and this is my javascript file:

```
$.getJSON('choosepizza.json', function (choosePizzaData){

    choosePizza(choosePizzaData);
});

function choosePizza(choosePizzaData){
    var botten = "";
    var topping = "";
    var extra = "";

    $(choosePizzaData).each(function (index, value){

        $(choosePizzaData[index].botten).each(function (ii,vv){
            botten = choosePizzaData[index].botten[ii];
            $('.box1_data').append((ii + 1) + "." + botten + `<input type="checkbox" name="${botten}"/>` + "<br>"); 
        });

        $(choosePizzaData[index].topping).each(function (ii,vv){
            topping = choosePizzaData[index].topping[ii];
            $('.box2_data').append((ii + 1) + "." + topping + `<input type="checkbox" name="${topping}"/>` + "<br>"); 
        });

        $(choosePizzaData[index].extra).each(function (ii,vv){
            extra = choosePizzaData[index].extra[ii];
            $('.box3').append((ii + 1) + "." + extra + `<input type="checkbox" name="${extra}"/>` + "<br>"); 
        });

    });
});
```

It's not working for me and I don't know why. The "botten" info from the json file is supposed to show up as a list in the div box1 from the HTML page, the topping in box2 etc. I've included my whole html this time and also i made a lot of changes to my script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get JSON data to show up in HTML div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852507/how-do-i-get-json-data-to-show-up-in-html-div)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this line of code: `$(choosePizzaData).each(...)`?  The jQuery .each() method is used to iterate over jQuery objects but you are applying it to JSON data.  Furthermore, you seem to be trying to cast JSON data into a jQuery object with `$(choosePizzaData)`, which doesn't really make sense.

If you're trying to access the data in your JSON file, use this notation.  For example, `choosePizzaData[0].botten` will get you the _botten_ and ``choosePizzaData[0].topping` will get you the _topping_, etc.

Comment: That will give you an array of each element which you need to iterate through.  The correct way to iterate depends on the parameters of your project.  If you want to use jQuery, you can use `$.each(array)` (which, by the way, is different from `$(element).each()` which you were using above.

Comment: Also, inside your `$.each(array)`, you will have your anonymous function which makes two variables available, `function(key, value) {...}` or, as you've written it, `function(ii, vv) {...}`.  Within this anonymous function, you _already_ have the value as ``vv`, no need for this strange syntax `choosePizzaData[index].botten[ii];`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is the kinda thing that you're looking for?

### Edit

I apologise if I've left something out or whatever, I'm not even sure what language this is in... So I've just taken an educated guess with a few things...

```js
// Wrap it all up in a name space so we can simulate having private properties. 
const PizzaApp = function(myNameSpace) {


  // Some in house stuff...
  const options = document.querySelector("#options");
  const root = document.querySelector("#app");
  const url = 'choosepizza.json';
  const state = {
    botten: null,
    topping: null,
    extra: null
  };


  // The method that gets the data from the server. 
  // For this example it's hard coded, but you get the idea?
  //
  // Mabe something like :- 
  // fetch(url).then(res => callback(res.json());
  const getData = callback => callback([{
      "botten": ["Krispig", "tunn"]
    },
    {
      "topping": ["kött", "kyckling", "tomat"]
    },
    {
      "extra": ["Fanta", "Coca cola", "Sprite"]
    }
  ]);


  // A function to render the user's option(s).
  const render = () => {
    root.innerHTML = `<p>Botten: ${state.botten == null ? 'N/A' : state.botten}</p>` +
      `<p>Topping: ${state.topping == null ? 'N/A' : state.topping}</p>` +
      `<p>Extra: ${state.extra == null ? 'N/A' : state.extra}</p>`;
  };


  // A function that fires when a state change has occured. 
  const onStateChange = () => render();


  // A function to handle the click events.
  // Made the assumption that you can only have one, but you could 
  // always update this so that you can append to have multiple. 
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    const p = e.target;
    const value = p.textContent;
    const property = p.className;
    state[property] = value;
    onStateChange();
  };


  // A function to add the event listeners to the options.
  const dispatchEvents = () => options.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => p.onclick = clickHandler);


  // A function to simply render the options.
  const optionsRender = data => {
    const template = o => {
      let el = options;

      switch (o.type) {
        case 'botten':
          el = options.querySelector('.box1');
          break;
        case 'topping':
          el = options.querySelector('.box2');
          break;
        case 'extra':
          el = options.querySelector('.box3');
          break;
      }

      el.innerHTML += `<p class="${o.type}">${o.value}</p>`;
    };

    data.forEach(i => Object.keys(i).map(k => i[k].map(v => template({
      value: v,
      type: k
    }))));

    dispatchEvents();
  };


  // A public, or even global function that is exposed through the name space as 
  // a way to start the app. 
  myNameSpace.launch = () => {
    getData(optionsRender);
    render(); // Initial render.
  };


  // Be sure the return the object. 
  return myNameSpace;
}({});


// Finally start the app. 
PizzaApp.launch();
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 960px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#options,
#app {
  max-width: calc(50% - 20px);
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 2.5px #888;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

#options p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#options .botten {
  color: red;
}

#options .topping {
  color: blue;
}

#options .extra {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code. You should ask your professor or a more experienced friend to help explain what you've done wrong.

Here is a concept of what you're trying to do. I intentionally did some things differently as to not do your homework for you.

```js
const data = [
  {
    botten: ["Krispig", "tunn"]
  },
  {
    topping: ["kött", "kyckling", "tomat"]
  },
  {
    extra: ["Fanta", "Coca cola", "Sprite"]
  }
]

data.forEach(function(dataObj){
  const category = Object.keys(dataObj)[0]
  const myList = $(`.${category}`)
  
  dataObj[category].forEach(function(element){
    myList.append(`<li><input type="checkbox" name="${element}">${element}</input></li>`)
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Välj botten</h2>
  <ol class="botten"></ol>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Välj topping</h2>
  <ol class="topping"></ol>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Välj tillebehör</h2>
  <ol class="extra"></ol>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I asked my more experienced friend and that's how I got this code :(

Comment: You should schedule office hours with your professor.  Hopefully he knows more than your friend.